# Добавление атрибута с множеством одинаковых значений

Tags: php, ldap

`ldap_modify` (да и `ldap_add`) выдает ошибку "Type or value exists", если попытаться добавить несколько одинаковых значений одному и тому же атрибуту.

Есть возможность с этим бороться? Типа "ignore this" вставить?

UPD: можно поставить "костыль", типа

```
nonuniquevalue_1
nonuniquevalue_2
nonuniquevalue_3
nonuniquevalue_4...
```

но хотелось бы по-человечески.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На [SO уже ответили](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141435/ldap-modify-add-identical-values-to-multivalue-attributes). Возможности такой нет, так как это нарушает протокол.
Собственно, решение уже нашел немного другое. В дереве создается новый уровень, в котором уникальные значения - ключи, а неуникальные - аттрибуты.